# How to perform operation during xml deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have 2 classes I'm serializing to save data.

```
[Serializable]
public class Album
{

    private string nom;
    [XmlElement]
    public string Nom
    {
        get { return nom; }
        set { nom = value; }
    }

    private List<Photo> photos = new List<Photo>();
    [XmlArray]
    public List<Photo> Photos
    {
        get { return photos; }
        set { photos = value; }
    }
...
}
```

And some photos:

```
[Serializable]
public class Photo
{
    private string nom;
    [XmlElement]
    public string Nom
    {
        get { return nom; }
        set { nom = value; }
    }

    private string path;
    [XmlElement]
    public string Path
    {
        get { return path; }
        set { path = value; }
    }

    private Image image;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Image Image
    {
        get { return image; }
        set { image = value; }
    }
...
}
```

As you can see, I'm not serializing the Bitmap Image. But when I deserialize my XML, I want the Bitmap object to be constructed in the same time.

A solution is to create the Bitmap Image with a loop after the deserialization, but I think there is a proper way.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the image creation logic in `setter of Path` property. Setter will be called for each de-serialized object.

```
[XmlElement]
public string Path
{
    get { return path; }
    set 
    { 
       path = value;
       // Image creation logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, tank you!